# Identify Column Number by defined Header String (ignore upper case, lower case, indentation)

Tags: excel, vba, formatting

I have a defined header string that I am trying to locate the respective column number for in a table. The table headers titles formats are indented with Alt+Enter.

The code works fine if the header string is written normally (without indentation) 
Sample: **Origin_Country(in 2-letter codes)**

In the excel table however the header format is different as mentioned. 
sample: 
**Origin_

Country

(in 2 letter format)**

Excel seems to think there is a space in the header due to the indentation and it is not recognized.

Did anyone encounter this and know a work around?

[image]

```
Option Compare Text
Option Explicit


Sub ListChanges()

Dim arrOrig, arrCurrent, delta, i As Long, ii As Long, r As Long, m
Dim rngOrig As Range, rngCurrent As Range, id, col As Long, vO, vC

Dim ls As String
Dim HeaderName As String, HeaderRow As Long
Dim j As Long

Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long, RowProcess As Long
Dim TopLeftAddress As String

'Origin Country
Dim OCountryCol As Long
Dim strOCountryCol As String

'DGF Lane ID
Dim DGFLaneIDCol As Long
Dim strDGFLaneIDCol As String

'Origin Region
Dim ORegionCol As Long
Dim strORegionCol As String

'------
Dim ActSht As Worksheet
Set ActSht = Worksheets(2)
    


        'ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(General).Range ("1:1")
        TopLeftAddress = ActSht.Range("1:1").Address  'identify top left cell of the table, to see where the table starts
        LastCol = ActSht.Range(TopLeftAddress).End(xlToRight).Column ' total number of columns in each pivot table
        i = ActSht.Range(TopLeftAddress).Column 'column number where the table starts
        HeaderRow = ActSht.Range("1:1").Row 'row number where the table starts
 
        For j = 25 To LastCol 'i set j at 25 so that I don't have to loop through all columns

        HeaderName = ActSht.Cells(HeaderRow, j)
        If InStr(HeaderName, "Origin_Country(in 2-letter codes)") > 0 Then
            OCountryCol = j
            strOCountryCol = Split(ActSht.Cells(, OCountryCol).Address, "$")(1)
            
            ElseIf InStr(HeaderName, "Origin_Region(enter AP, AM, EURO, MEA)") > 0 Then
                ORegionCol = j
                strORegionCol = Split(ActSht.Cells(, ORegionCol).Address, "$")(1)
            End If
        Next
        
    


Set rngOrig = Original.Cells(1).CurrentRegion
Set rngCurrent = Current.Cells(1).CurrentRegion

arrOrig = rngOrig.Value
arrCurrent = rngCurrent.Value

ReDim delta(1 To UBound(arrCurrent, 1) * (UBound(arrCurrent, 2)), 1 To 8) 'max possible size

delta(1, 1) = "Location"
delta(1, 2) = "Original Value"
delta(1, 3) = "Changed Value"
delta(1, 4) = "Deviation"
delta(1, 5) = "Header"
delta(1, 6) = "Row ID"
delta(1, 7) = "Origin Region"
delta(1, 8) = "Origin Country"

r = 1 'row in delta array

For i = 2 To UBound(arrCurrent, 1)
    id = arrCurrent(i, 1)
    'find the corresponding row
    m = Application.Match(id, rngOrig.Columns(1), 0)
    If Not IsError(m) Then
        For col = 2 To UBound(arrCurrent, 2)
            vO = arrOrig(m, col)
            vC = arrCurrent(i, col)
            If (Len(vC) > 0 Or Len(vO) > 0) And vC <> vO Then
                r = r + 1
                delta(r, 1) = rngCurrent.Cells(i, col).Address(False, False)
                delta(r, 2) = vO
                delta(r, 3) = vC
                If Len(vO) > 0 And Len(vC) > 0 Then
            
                    If IsNumeric(vO) And IsNumeric(vC) Then
                        delta(r, 4) = vC / vO - 1  'eg
                    End If
                End If
                delta(r, 5) = arrCurrent(1, col) 'header
                delta(r, 6) = arrCurrent(i, 1)   'id
                delta(r, 7) = arrCurrent(i, 26) 'id region
                delta(r, 8) = arrCurrent(i, 27) 'id country
            End If
        Next col
    Else
        'no id match, just record the cell address and the current id
        r = r + 1
        delta(r, 1) = rngCurrent.Cells(i, 1).Address(False, False)
        delta(r, 6) = id
    End If
 Next
With Changes
    .Activate
    .Cells(1).CurrentRegion.Clear
    .[a1].Resize(r, UBound(delta, 2)) = delta '<< edited here
    With .Cells(1).CurrentRegion
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        With Rows(1).Font
            .Size = 12
            .Bold = 1
        End With
        .Columns.AutoFit
    End With
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: `OCountryCol = Application.Match("*(in 2 letter format)*",ActSht.Range("1:1"),0)`

Comment: that is what that code will do.  It will return the column number where the string contains `(in 2 letter format)` in the first row of the sheet.

Comment: Try this: `"Origin_" & vbLf & "Country" & vbLf & "(in 2 letter format)"`.

Comment: @ScottCraner ok thanks, I had misunderstood. Replaced the "If Instr loop" with the application.match line but am getting a type mismatch error.

Comment: Check the spelling in the the match of that part.  You have three different versions in your question and it may not be correct.

Comment: Instead of `If InStr(HeaderName, "Origin_Country(in 2-letter codes)") > 0 Then` try `If StrComp(HeaderName, "Origin_" & vbLf & "Country" & vbLf & "(in 2 letter format)", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then`

Comment: If you're talking about the `StrComp`-line, then it is working by chance. It has to be 0 (equality). Check your string for spaces or invisible characters at the beginning or the end. Also you can use the same string in the `Instr`-line where you can use either `> 0` or `= 1`, the latter being more accurate. BTW, `Instr` also has a `Compare` argument.